# c# Xna turned off FixedTimeStep but still update calls max. 60 times

Tags: c#, xna

Hi guys i just made a small Algorithm to display the fps to my screen.

```
        frames_temp++;
        frames_Time += (int)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
        if (frames_Time >= 1000)
        {
            frames = frames_temp;
            frames_temp = 0; frames_Time = 0;
        }
```

this code snipped is located in the Update-method. The frame variable stores the actual value drawn to the screen(just posting that code, to make sure there is no fault, eventhough i checked it already). 
Now the problem is that i can't turn off the IsFixedTimeStep. I set it to false inside the constructor, initialize and even the update-method but still the programm limits my fps to ~60. I either put in a for() query into my update-method running many million loops without frame-drops to make sure its not my cpu beeing too slow .Another thing i already tried is to use my own timeSpan and the systemtime to get the elapsed time between the calls of Update(), wich gives me kinda the same output. Now it is 99% sure that update only runs 60 times a second.

So why can't i call the Update-Method as often as possible as it should be when IsFixedTimeStep is false

Ty for replies

Comment: its not your computer. the limit of 60 fps is to follow your monitor refresh rate. look at vertical syncing like ISun said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that you problem is [Vertical Syncing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_synchronization#Vertical_synchronization), this function of the graphics device is locking the frame rate to your monitor refresh rate. To solve this problem you need to turn off VSync (`SynchronizeWithVerticalRetrace`) in the `GraphicsDeviceManager`:

```
graphicsDeviceManager.SynchronizeWithVerticalRetrace = false;
graphicsDeviceManager.ApplyChanges();
```

`graphicsDeviceManager` is your game's `GraphicsDeviceManager`

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correct fixed timestep = false results in the update being called before the draw method, not calling it as often as possible. Therefore you should check wheter Vsync or something else is limiting your application to 60fps.